# Azure Pipeline Google Tests not running as .EXE

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, googletest

I'm transitioning a traditional C++ code base build to the Azure DevOps Pipeline.  We have a bunch of gtest unit tests in a module that is just an executable named "sdktests.exe".  It links to gtest 1.8.1.  The user has always just manually run this exe and observed the results.

But I can't seem to make it Azure Devops detect and run these tests.  I'm guessing that it needs the tests in the form of a DLL that it loads instead of an EXE

**Is that the case? Do I need to convert my google tests module from an EXE to a DLL to make this work?**

This is my yaml pipeline step

```
- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: '**\*sdktests*.exe'
```

This is my Azure build output for the step:

```
Source filter: **\*sdktests*.exe
SystemVssConnection exists true
d:\a\_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.170.1\Modules\DTAExecutionHost.exe --inputFile d:\a\_temp\input_484b64d0-c544-11ea-bc95-251e50750ee7.json
======================================================
##########################################################################
DtaExecutionHost version 18.170.30112.1.
Starting TestExecution Model...
Result Attachments will be stored in LogStore
Run Attachments will be stored in LogStore
Result Attachments will be stored in LogStore
Result Attachments will be stored in LogStore
Run Attachments will be stored in LogStore
Updated Run Settings:
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <BatchSize>1000</BatchSize>
    <ResultsDirectory>d:\a\_temp\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
  </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
**************** Starting test execution *********************
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe "@d:\a\_temp\jcgckxlo13t.tmp"
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 16.6.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
vstest.console.exe "d:\a\1\s\x64\Release\sdktests.exe"
/Settings:"d:\a\_temp\ktasri4fewz.tmp.runsettings"
/Logger:"trx"
/TestAdapterPath:"d:\a\1\s"
Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
No test is available in d:\a\1\s\x64\Release\sdktests.exe. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
```

Comment: You need to use a supported test framework and test adapter. What research have you done so far?

Comment: I know I need to use a supported test framework and adapter.  I've found many discussions.  But I'm not asking "How do I get google test to build my tests on Azure Devops"  I'm asking if my tests need to be in the form of a DLL.  I cannot find a definitive answer, just examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Joe,

I have run into a similar situation in the past. Here is what I found. If you are running GTest you should be running as you would normally, no need to us VSTest task. The test result file that is generated by GTest is in a JUnit formatted XML file. You can use the publish test results v2 task to publish to the build. The setup would look something like:

```
- task: CmdLine@1
  displayName: Run Unit Tests (GTest)
  inputs:
    script: 'sdktests.exe'

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: Publish Unit Test Results (GTest)
  inputs:
    testResultsFiles: '**/SDKTestResults.xml'
    testRunTitle: 'GTest Results'
```

Here are references that you should use to create a solution that meets your needs:

- [Publish Test Results - Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)
- [Command Line - Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Comment: Wow this seems much better.  I think I'll aim for this

Comment: @Joe - Yeah, I actually tried the same approach you did at first and couldn't get it to work properly. I found an article somewhere in the ether regarding how GTest results can be published using the PublishTestRestuls@2 task. I implemented this in my pipeline and have had success with it.

Comment: Works like a champ.  Great call.  Thanks!